# POJO from HBM file

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hbm2java

HI all,

I am new to hibernate  and I would to create POJO from xxx.hbm.xml file.

Is it possible? Please respond.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) include an Ant Task allowing to generate Java code from mapping files (amongst other things). Check the section [4.4.2. POJO java code exporter (<hbm2java>)](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html_single/#d0e2903) in the documentation.

The [Hibernate3 Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/) also supports this (with the [`hibernate3:hbm2java`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2java-mojo.html) goal).