# generating class from hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate, class

i have one mapping file viz. student.hbm.xml.. i need to generate Student.java from the same. the file is below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.hibernate.entity.ClassRoom" table="class_room">
        <id name="roomId" column="room_id" type="int"/>
        <property name="roomClass" column="room_class" type="string"/>
        <property name="floor" column="floor" type="int"/>
        <property name="roomMaster" column="room_mast" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

is there any way i can create the class file from the above file.please help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [POJO from HBM file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711408/pojo-from-hbm-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) (install it in eclipse).

OR

Develop custom maven plugin... (sample code available below)

```
/**
 * Generate POJO from *.hbm.xml 
 * Example Usage: mvn prefix:hbm2pojo OR 
 *                mvn prefix:hbm2pojo -Dexec.args="com.comp.Product,com.comp.Item"
 *
 * @goal hbm2pojo
 */
public class GenerateHibernatePojoMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
    /** Directory for hibernate mapping files
     * @parameter expression="${basedir}/src/main/resources"
     * @required
     */
    private File hbmDirectory;

    /** Output directory for POJOs
     * @parameter expression="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"
     * @required
     */
    private File outputDirectory;

    /** set to true if collections need to use generics. Default is false.
     * @parameter expression="${jdk5}" default-value="false"
     * @optional
     */
    private String jdk5;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {
        POJOExporter exporter = new POJOExporter();
        exporter.setOutputDirectory( outputDirectory );

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setProperty("jdk5", jdk5);

        String args = System.getProperty("exec.args");
        if (args != null && !"".equals(args))
        {
            String[] entityNames = args.split(",");
            for(String entityName : entityNames)
            {
                File hbmFile = new File( hbmDirectory + "/" + entityName.replace( '.', '/' ) + ".hbm.xml" );
                config.addFile( hbmFile );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            config.addDirectory( hbmDirectory );
        }
        exporter.setConfiguration( config );
        exporter.start();
        // TODO this guy also generates unwanted POJOs like POJO of component
        // TODO Add support for Java 5 Generic
    }

}
```

- SE

Comment: can u please tell me from where to get the maven jar.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Btw, you can get all most all jars from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

- SE

Answer (score 1):

Try [hibernate tools](http://www.redhat.com/developer_studio/guides/hibernatetools/html_single/#codegen) using *hbm2java* ant target. Example [1](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/12/14/hibernate-class-generation-with-hbm2java.html) and [2](http://www.coderanch.com/t/219298/ORM/java/hibernate-ant-task-hbm-java)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Hibernate tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) with [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/index.html)