# DAO generation with POJO and hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have my POJOs and hibernate mapping xmls with me. With these how do i generate DAOs?

Can you please help me with a plugin in eclipse or any other relevant methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711408/pojo-from-hbm-file). In general you have to use [hbm2java](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html_single/#d0e2903) tool.