# how to generate Hibernate Mapping class from *.hbm.xml class

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hbm

I want make a generic hibernate API which will create mapping class from hbm.xml and use in generic select method.

Please help me..

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [POJO from HBM file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711408/pojo-from-hbm-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate tools (hbm2java) allows you to do this. Read the [5.4.2. POJO java code exporter section](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.1.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/#d0e4821) or look at the screenshot below.

[image: POJO java code exporter (<hbm2java>)]
<sub>(Screenshot from [Hibernate Tools Reference Guide [pdf]](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/7.1/pdf/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio-7.1-Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide-en-US.pdf))</sub>

Comment: @johnny fixed the link